# Local isometry which is not covering map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, isometry

The theorem of Ambrose establishes that given a local isometry between two connected Riemannian manifolds $(M, g)$ and $(N,h)$ if $M$ is complete then $f$ is a covering.

I was wondering why completeness is necessary and I was trying to construct a local isometry which is not a covering until I realized that I do not know of many examples of local isometries, particularly on non complete manifolds such as the punctured plane.

Does anyone know of a few examples?

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the local isometry condition tells you that your map has the sort of local covering property that is really at the heart of covering spaces. The problem is that the map may not be surjective. For instance, take the inclusion map from the punctured plane into the plane. This is clearly a local isometry, but it is not surjective. Thus the map does not have the covering property near the origin $(0,0)$ in the codomain.

So really, you should think of local isometries as being like covering spaces. After all, if you were just to complete the domain and codomain and uniquely extend the map $f$, you *would* have a covering space.

Comment: Thank you so much